# Cordova build does not update project

Tags: ios, cordova, build

something weird is happening and I don't know why (The first time this happens to me).

I have my Cordova project that I'm testing in my iPhone (I work on MacBook Pro), but, the 3rd time I did `cordova build ios` I noticed somethig weird in my app as nothing had changed. (That happened yesterday)

Since then I've been making changes (even deleting complete files) but it doesn't matter how many times I build, nothing changes in my phone.

When building, it ends with `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **` so I really don't understand why this is happening.

```
$ cordova build ios
Running command: /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/cordova/build 
2015-04-10 10:41:33.992 xcodebuild[1943:1007] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID A16FF353-8441-459E-A50C-B071F53F51B7 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/SparkInspectorXcodePlugin.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator8.2
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
    VALID_ARCHS = i386

=== BUILD TARGET CordovaLib OF PROJECT CordovaLib WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

=== BUILD TARGET LolApi OF PROJECT LolApi WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ www\ directory build/LolApi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LolApi.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh
    cd /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/build/LolApi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LolApi.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh

real    0m0.243s
user    0m0.032s
sys 0m0.058s

ProcessInfoPlistFile build/emulator/LolApi.app/Info.plist LolApi/LolApi-Info.plist
    cd /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin"
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/LolApi/LolApi-Info.plist -genpkginfo /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/build/emulator/LolApi.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -additionalcontentfile /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/build/LolApi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LolApi.build/MainViewController-PartialInfo.plist -o /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/build/emulator/LolApi.app/Info.plist

GenerateDSYMFile build/emulator/LolApi.app.dSYM build/emulator/LolApi.app/LolApi
    cd /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/build/emulator/LolApi.app/LolApi -o /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/build/emulator/LolApi.app.dSYM

Touch build/emulator/LolApi.app
    cd /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin"
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/myuser/Documents/project/platforms/ios/build/emulator/LolApi.app

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

All changes where made in `project/www` folder, not in `project/platform/ios/`

Comment: In which folder did you delete those files? In the folder from the OS so for iOS in -> Platforms -> iOS -> www or in the main folder -> www?

Comment: I deleted and modified in www, when modified I did build to see new changes in iPhone. I do it this way because I use server connection and if I test on browser nothing works, but it does on device

Comment: You use the server connection for what exactly? Try to clear the cache of your browser.

Comment: I use https://github.com/claudiowilson/LeagueJS api in client side, for that I used http://browserify.org/ I really think cache doesn't have anything to do with it as I test it directly on device

Comment: You said that it works fine on your device so i talked about the browser cache.

Comment: I said it doesn't update on device, that's the question

Comment: I'm editing to add response in Terminal so you can see what happens

Comment: try with "cordova prepare ios" before the "cordova build ios", build should run prepare first, but maybe something is not working well. Try with "cordova run ios --device" too

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however, I was using Cordova with React and I had npm scripts prepared in `package.json`:

`"cordova:start:ios": "npm run build:cordova && cp -a ./dist/. ./.cordova/www && cd ./.cordova && cordova run ios"`

If I used Cordova commands directly `cordova build ios` the app wouldn't register the changes. Only when I used the command above it would work.

I came across [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178559/2855029) with somebody using Ionic. They also were bypassing Ionic preset build commands and using Cordova directly, which caused them the same issue.