# iOS App doesn't update on ionic 2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ionic2

I started to develop ionic 2 cordova app on mac and doesn't update ios Application. 
My pc specs are,

`node v8.9.1
npm v5.5.1
cordova v7.1.0
ionic v3.17.0
editor VSCode`

if I want some code change in ionic-v1 then I can edit  `platform -> ios -> www ->.js` files or  `platform -> ios -> www ->.html` files and reload xcode then changes appear on real device.

But in ionic 2 app `platform -> ios -> www` folder contain minified files and cannot edit these files. so I follow this process but code doesn't change.

1. Add ios platform to project using `cordova platform add ios` and run ios app on xcode. initial app runs fine
2. then go to `project -> src -> pages ->home ->home.component.ts`  edit home.component.ts and home.component.html
3. run `cordova prepare` to add changes to ios platform
4. stop xcode and `clean->build->run` project again.. changes doesn't appear.
5. remove ios platform using `cordova platform remove ios` and readd it using `cordova platform add ios` then new changes are appear.

I develop ionic-v1 and ionic 2 apps on windows and those are working perfectly on device.
what is the correct procedure to develop ionic 2 app on mac and dedug it correctly.
any help could be appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit**
Please note that I’m facing this issue in ionic 2 app run on my physical iPhone

Answer (score 1):

Step 3. is the problem. You are directly running `cordova prepare` command.

Use the [ionic cli](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/prepare/).

```
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

> Copies assets to Cordova platforms, preparing them for native builds

which means it copies resources from your assets folder to your platforms. This doesnt update your build with the code changes.

You should be using,

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

For running you can do `ionic cordova run ios` or `ionic cordova emulate ios`.

Comment: tried both ways
1.run cordova prepare then cordova build ios after that stop xcode and clean->build->run project again.
2.run ionic cordova prepare ios then ionic cordova build ios after that stop xcode and clean->build->run project again.
But no luck for both ways new changes doesn’t appear.

Comment: I need to run this app on physical device. because it use device camera, storage ect. normally in ionic v1 I do this way.
1. start app project -> platform -> ios -> .MyApp.xcodeproj on xcode and run it on my iPhone
2. start safari and inspect using safari -> Develop -> iPhone and debug here and do changes
but I cannot do this way in ionic 2. because my changes under src doesn't appear on my iPhone

Comment: see my above comment

Comment: using ionic cordova run ios I cannot run app on physical device

Comment: you are my new hero.. :)
before it works ask me to install "ios-deploy" npm module
after that it works nicely.. 
thanks